# C# How to "array.add" to an array of a dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

Imagine that you have a dictionary like that:

```
Dictionary<int, int[]> dict = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
```

So what I want to do is to ".add" to the value like a normal array.

I know I can add a Key and a Value like that:

```
dict.Add(0, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
```

So I have this: `Key=0, Value=[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

But what happen if I want to add a "5" at the value of the "Key=0" in order to make it appears like `Key=0, Value=[1, 2, 3, 4, *5*]`?

Comment: What you have to do is to extract the array and create a new one with the `5` at the end of it since Arrays have fixed size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify an an array inside a dictionary you could use LINQ's `Append()`:

```
dict[0] = dict[0].Append(5).ToArray();
```

But you should not use arrays if you want to modify them. Use `List<T>` instead:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

dict.Add(0, new List<int> {1,2,3,4});
```

Then you can call `Append()` on the list inside the dictionary:

```
dict[0].Append(5);
```

Comment: Try `dict[0].Add(5)` given a List<int> inside a Dictionary 